# How to transfer Pro Tools LE 8 license (authorization code) from one computer to another?

Tags: windows, license, transfer, product-key, pro-tools

I am getting ready to wipe and sell a computer for my friend, and he needs me to transfer his copy of Pro Tools LE 8 to his new computer. He can't find the original packaging for it, and I've downloaded it instead. Now I need the authorization code (which I suppose is like a Windows product key, I hope), and I have the old computer which as not yet been wiped. The old one is running Windows XP, new one is Windows 7. Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder didn't find the key (free version), and I'm not looking to pirate it. How can I transfer the code off the old computer? I need to at least find it, because the old one is not connected to the Internet.

Comment: The best way.  Contact the company and request assistance in this matter.

Comment: They need you to pay a fee for support. I'm not sure if it's even supported. It's an older version and the newest is version 11.

Comment: Is there any alternative to MJB keyfinder that includes Pro Tools? I didn't see it in the list of supported programs.

Comment: I have had luck with Belarc Advisor.  I have another alternative but won't suggest it because of the additional useless software that is installed unless extract the portable application from the installer itself.

Comment: It didn't list it... Anything else? The computer is going to be wiped so it's okay if it installs useless crap (unless it's malware).

Comment: The only alternative is to SysPrep Windows, clone the hdd, and restore it to the new computer

Comment: I can't... It needs to be running Windows 7, and it has so many junk programs that it would just be better to get the product key. I was thinking, what about Process Monitor?

Comment: Process Monitor won't give you the license key.  The idea behind the migration would be to simply update the Windows XP to Windows 7.  It sounds like you will need to purchase support to get the license key.